# Change Like button colour when a post is liked

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

i have this social media application and i want when a user has liked a post the colour is red and if not it is black.
Here is my view:

```
@login_required()
def likes(request, post_id):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    current_likes = post.likes

    liked = Likes.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).count()
    if not liked:
        liked = Likes.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
        current_likes = current_likes + 1

    else:
        liked = Likes.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).delete()
        current_likes = current_likes - 1

    post.likes = current_likes
    post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[post_id]))
```

my post-detail.html page and index.html look like:

```
 <a href="{% url 'like' post.id %}" class="post__button">
    {% if post.likes %}
        <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: red; font-size: 27px;"></i>
    {% else %}
         <i class="fa-regular fa-heart" style="color: black; font-size: 27px;"></i>
    {% endif %}
 </a>
```

But saying "if post.likes" works if the post has any like even if not from the current user and makes the like button red and if the post has 0 likes it is black.
But i want it like that with the current logged in user (user=request.user)

i have tried the following in the html to no avail

```
if user.post.likes
if request.user.post.likes
if not liked
if liked
```

urls.py

```
 path('<uuid:post_id>/like', views.likes, name="like"),
```

model.py

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_likes")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_likes")
```

Answer (score 1):

How I have it is I use a manytomany field in my Post model. `likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')`
I also added a function to the model called `total_likes()`.

```
def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Then I create a view that will add and remove users from the list.

```
@login_required
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

Then in my view I create a liked variable.

```
stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
liked = False
if stuff.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    liked = True
```

Then I use a little bit of logic in my template to display Two different buttons.

```
{% if user.username == post.author.username %}
<h5>You cannot vote on your own post!</h5>
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}{% if liked %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Unlike</button> -
    {{ total_likes }} Like/s
    {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Like</button>
    -
    {{ total_likes }} Like/s
    {% endif %}
</form>
  
{% endif %}
```

*I hope this helps!*

Comment: The urls are the same ` path('user/like/<int:pk>', UserLikeView, name='like_user'),`